# Could you share with me information about [...] in Dart?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I've solved several solutions on Codewars and saw that one solution uses [...], I tried to google what it is, but google only finds how to create arrays (List a = [1, 2, 3]), how to get the second element, etc.

Solution: `List<int> reverseList(List<int> list)=>[...list.reversed]`;

Comment: It is the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Dart when we use the three dots (...) it means that we are unpacking one and taking its values and throwing it, so when we have

```
List<int> reverseList(List<int> list)=>[...list.reversed]
```

means that we take the reverse `list`, unpack it and throw it in another List that you are creating